# uv__queue_done: Assertion

Tags: libuv, node.js-addon

- **Node.js Version**:6.9
- **OS**:linux
- **Scope (install, code, runtime, meta, other?)**:
- **Module (and version) (if relevant)**:
- **Project Adress**: https://github.com/dreamyzhang/nodectp

### Question 1:

It would be coredump when run some time.  as follows:
node: src/threadpool.c:252: uv__queue_done: Assertion `(((const QUEUE *) (&(req->loop)->active_reqs) == (const QUEUE *) (*(QUEUE **) &((*(&(req->loop)->active_reqs))[0]))) == 0)' failed.

### Question 2:

the same node version 6.9.   when installed by nvm  will coredump like  #485.

Comment: Are you calling uv_queue_work from a thread which is not the loop thread?

Comment: uv_queue_work is not thread-safe？ because my app is multithreading, so  I use it for thread communication.

Comment: void uv__work_submit(uv_loop_t* loop,
                         struct uv__work* w,
                         void (*work)(struct uv__work* w),
                         void (*done)(struct uv__work* w, int status)) {
      uv_once(&once, init_once);
      w->loop = loop;
      w->work = work;
      w->done = done;
      post(&w->wq);
    } 
    static void post(QUEUE* q) {
  uv_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  QUEUE_INSERT_TAIL(&wq, q);    
  if (idle_threads > 0)
    uv_cond_signal(&cond);
  uv_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}---------------------->>it is locked in libuv.

Comment: No, uv_queue_work is not thread-safe. You must call it from the loop thread. See http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/design.html#the-i-o-loop

Comment: Those locks are because the thread pool is shared across loops.

Comment: uv_async_init also is not thread-safe.  So I init a pool of uv_async_t for using by uv_async_send.   it is ok  and it had been  pushed to the git.

Comment: Yep, that will work :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220524/uv-queue-done-assertion?noredirect=1#comment73652659_43220524) as an answer:

You are using `uv_queue_work` from a thread which is not the loop thread. This is not supported behavior (the loop API is not thread-safe unless stated otherwise, which is not the case).

The threading model is defined [here](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/design.html#the-i-o-loop).